# PHP-MySql Help on Selecting records from two tables to make Journal (in Accountancy)

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

1. outward - the data of all transactions happens day by day
2. receipt - information about money received

   outward:

   ```
   bill_No      date            perticular      amount      cust_Id     cust_Name
   1           2013-06-21       Any Item 1      1250           1        Vikram
   2           2013-06-21       Any Item 2      1500           1        Vikram 
   ------- & so on------
   ```

   receipt:

   ```
   rec_Id     date              payment_mode     amount     cust_Id     cust_Name
   1         2013-06-21         Cash             1000        1          Vikram
   2         2013-06-22         Cash             1750        1          Vikram
   ------- & so on------
   ```

EXPECTED OUTPUT (on screen):

```
Date            Particulars       Bill No     Debit        Credit        Balance
2013-06-21      Any Item 1           1         1250          -
2013-06-21      Any Item 2           1         1250          -
2013-06-21      Cash                 -           -          1000
2013-06-22      Cash                 -           -          1750
```

I want to do is: [for making of Journal]
To collect all the records of a particular customer (cust_Name) from both the tables and sort them according to dates
[on same date: first get the record from outward table and then from receipt].

What query should I perform?

P.s. - I will calculate the balance by my own.

Comment: OK, your problem is quite well stated. However, we do like to see prior effort here. You have mentioned two queries you'd like to build, can we see your attempt at the first one, say? It's a `SELECT` with a `JOIN`.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM outward As Tb1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM receipt As Tb2 WHERE Tb1.custId='".$custId."' AND Tb2.custId='".$custId."' ORDER BY date ASC"

(luck at the syntax first not the field names...)

Comment: How did you plan to calculate and output the balance? Can you edit your question and show in expected output what balance values should be on each line of your report based on the sample data?

Comment: I have changed my mind....
Now, I am going to calculate the balance at the end...
not on every line...
I can make that happen but my first concern is to get records from both the table by date sequence...
[If still its not clear to you then i will surly edit the question or insert an edited screenshot image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```sql
SELECT date, perticular, bill_No, debit, credit, balance
  FROM
(
  SELECT date, perticular, bill_No, amount debit, NULL credit, NULL balance, 1 ord
    FROM outward
   WHERE cust_id = 1
   UNION ALL
  SELECT date, payment_mode, NULL, NULL, amount, NULL, 2
    FROM receipt
   WHERE cust_id = 1
) q
ORDER BY date, ord
```

Output:

```
|       DATE | PERTICULAR | BILL_NO |  DEBIT | CREDIT | BALANCE |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 2013-06-21 | Any Item 1 |       1 |   1250 | (null) |  (null) |
| 2013-06-21 | Any Item 2 |       2 |   1500 | (null) |  (null) |
| 2013-06-21 |       Cash |  (null) | (null) |   1000 |  (null) |
| 2013-06-22 |       Cash |  (null) | (null) |   1750 |  (null) |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37954/3)** demo

Comment: please help me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22065196/mysql-database-design-query-for-such-ledger-report